# Merge / alias tags: multihomed and multi-homed

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[multihomed](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/multihomed) [multi-homed](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/multi-homed)

Filler, filler, 30 characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done and done